# ANTLR: mismatched input

Tags: antlr

I couldn't understand a bug in my grammar. The file, Bug.g4, is:

```
grammar Bug;

text: TEXT;

WORD: ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+ ;
TEXT: ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+ ;

NEWLINE: [\n\r] -> skip ;
```

After running antlr4 and javac, I run

```
grun Bug text -tree
aa
line 1:0 mismatched input 'aa' expecting TEXT
(text aa)
```

But if I instead use text: WORD in the grammar, things are okay. What's wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When two lexer rules each match the same string of text, and no other lexer rule matches a *longer* string of text, ANTLR assigns the token type according to the rule which appeared first in the grammar. In your case, a `TEXT` token can never be produced by the lexer rule because the `WORD` rule will always match the same text and the `WORD` rule appears before the `TEXT` rule in the grammar. If you were to reverse the order of these rules in the grammar, you would start to see `TEXT` tokens but you would never see a `WORD` token.